# variable is not being intitialised

Tags: java

```
String firstname , middlename , lastname ;

firstname = fn.getText().substring(0,1);
middlename = mn.getText().substring(0,1);
lastname = ln.getText();

String shortname = shortname.concat(lastname); // error is in this line, shortname.concat

shortname = shortname.concat(" ");
shortname = shortname.concat(firstname);
shortname = shortname.concat(".");
shortname = shortname.concat("middlename");
shortname = shortname.concat(".");

shrt.setText(shortname);
```

No other lines have any error. just `shortname` variable not initialised.

*Note: EASY SOLUTIONS PLEASE. I AM IN CLASS 11. DOING THIS JAVA OUT OF TEXT BOOK.*

Comment: Please, edit your post with the error [stack trace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace)

Comment: @Christian that'd be a compile error ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use `shortname` even before declaring it. You need to declare it and initialize a variable before using it. The use of `shortname` on the RHS means that you're trying to use it even before it has been declared on the LHS. Declare and initialize it first, and then use it.

```
String shortname = ""; // blank string, for initializing it
shortname = shortname.concat(lastname);
```

As [@Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300208/variable-is-not-being-intitialised#comment32101192_21300244) has commented, if its going to be a concat with a blank string, you might as well just directly assign the value to it. And that way you need not have 2 statements.

```
String shortname = lastname; // Declaration and initialization, done!
```

Answer (score 5):

The *right-hand* expression in

```
String shortname = shortname.concat(lastname);
```

will be evaluated *before* the assignment, so when you try to do

```
shortname.concat(lastname)
```

`shortname` at that moment is not initialized. To fix this you must **initialize it** with an empty string (`""`) before you use it:

```
String shortname = "";
shortname = shortname.concat(...);
```

**Edit:**

As @BrianRoach commented, is not necessary to concatenate it, since you are just concatenating a empty string (`""`) with another `String`. Just do:

```
String shortname = lastname;
```

Comment: Why concat at all when we know it's empty? `String shortName = lastName`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
  String shortname = "";
  shortname = shortname.concat(lastname);
```

Comment: Why concat at all when we know it's empty? String shortName = lastName

Comment: No need at all to concat with empty string

Answer (score 0):

Initilize shortname first

```
Actulally shortname doesnt contain anything to concat with.
```

So provide some value for it,

```
String shortname="";
shortname = shortname.concat(lastname);
```

Edit:

as @BrianRoach commented in @Christians answer,we should initilize shortname as

```
String shortname=lastname;
```

to value the purpose of concatenation.

Comment: @BrianRoach : i was already undergoing the edit, by seeing your comment in Christian's answer..!!

Comment: I just posted the same comment to all of them ;)